# AWS - Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Server app: node + S3 integration.

using the package `aws-sdk`.

getting the error in the response of `S3.getSignedUrl({Bucket, Key, Expires})`.

Response Error:

```
Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys 
require AWS Signature Version 4
```

**Code**

```
export const platformS3 = new S3({
  region: process.env.PLATFORM_S3_REGION,
});

const SIGNED_URL_EXPIRED_SECONDS = 300;

export const getSignedUrl = async ({
  id,
  bucket,
  pathInBucket,
}: FileUpload) => {

  const fileUrl = platformS3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: pathInBucket,
    Expires: SIGNED_URL_EXPIRED_SECONDS,
  });

  return { fileUrl };
};
```

How to solve the error ?

**EDIT 1**

S3 config:

```
region: eu-west-1
aws-sdk: ^2.1238.0
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution was found here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1970

Add `signatureVersion: 'v4'` to the `S3` client init.

**Code**

```
const platformS3 = new S3({
  signatureVersion: 'v4', <--
  region: process.env.PLATFORM_S3_REGION,
});
```

Comment: What region are you targeting? What version of the library are you using? The issue has been solved over 3 years ago. This should not be necessary at all anymore.

Comment: @luk2302 hi, this is the s3 config:

region: eu-west-1,
aws-sdk: ^2.1238.0

Comment: If that is actually the case you should open a bug ticket in the repository, because that would be a bug. I doubt that is really happening, sounds and looks more like an issue if your setup.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the S3 access policy for this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).